# Developing C++ WinUI3 Desktop App with MVVM

Tags: windows-10, winui, winui-3

I am looking at the [WinUI3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/get-started-winui3-for-desktop) framework with native C++ support for desktop applications.
I cannot see any MVVM support as in C#.
 Should I expect it will be never supported and go i.e. with MVP with some code behind, or I am missing something?
I cannot find any sample.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about automatic tooling for XAML than you have to wait until 2024 to use it with C++. This is the estimated timeline from MS as they first hebr yo push a reflection API into the C++2023 standard.

But the MVVM fundamentals are perfectly working. Just write it out by hand and enjoy a developer experience last seen in 2006.

Answer (score 0):

You can do MVVM by implementing interfaces such as INotifyPropertyChanged manually. Check out this [sample](https://github.com/johanlindfors/MvvmCppWinRT/blob/master/Framework/BindableBase.h) which showcases how to implement the interface.

The cppxaml library (part of the [unpackaged](https://nuget.org/packages/Unpackaged) NuGet package) has been providing some help with MVVM though it's very barebones compared to MVVM frameworks available for .NET apps.